# python script to run on every file in a directory

Tags: python, csv, uuid

I have a python script which takes the file and process that file. However, because I have 1198 files which need the same processing, I was wondering whether the command argument section could be modified with a for loop to consecutively run through all the files in a folder?

The code for the system argument is here:

```
import csv
import uuid

fin = open('input.csv', 'rb')
fout = open('output.csv', 'w')

reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

firstrow = True
for row in reader:
    if firstrow:
        row.append('UUID')
        firstrow = False
    else:
        row.append(uuid.uuid4())
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: yeas. all files are in .csv format.

Comment: `glob`or `os.listdir` are your friends.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os

myPath = 'D:\\2000ad'   
myFiles=os.listdir(myPath)
for f in myFiles:
    print f
```

This will return a list of all the files in a given folder & you can just loop through the list.

Comment: OP asked about modifying specific section of code. If you wanted to mention how list iteration workss, that should come as a comment. and I would personally prefer seeing `for filenamein os.listdir(my_path): print(filename)`

Comment: my intention was to show that `os.listdir()` existed.

Comment: again, that's what comments are for. press the `answer` button only with full answers.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can loop over a list of files and you will probably discover many ways to do this.

Example - You can use the os.listdir function

```
import os

files = [fi for fi in os.listdir(pathtofiles) if fi.endswith('.csv')]
```

This will do the same as DrBwts answer except only files ending with .csv will be added to the list.  Or you can do the following if you need the full path to the files as your input.

```
import os

fullpathfiles = [pathtofiles + fi for fi in os.listdir(pathtofiles) if fi.endswith('.csv')]
```